# What's the difference between balances.account and system.account?

Tags: balances

What's the difference between the balances reported by the `balances.account` and `system.account` storage queries?

I would expect a balance query on a development chain for 'Alice' to show me a funded balance, but `balances.account` gives me:

```
{
  free: 0
  reserved: 0
  frozen: 0
  flags: 170,141,183,460,469,231,731,687,303,715,884,105,728
}
```

while `system.account` gives me:

```
{
  nonce: 8
  consumers: 1
  providers: 1
  sufficients: 0
  data: {
    free: 1,152,921,504,575,215,358
    reserved: 0
    frozen: 0
    flags: 170,141,183,460,469,231,731,687,303,715,884,105,728
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Typically, we store the system account and native balances together. However, in some cases, your chain may have multiple instances of native tokens (pallet-balances). In such situations, you might need to store additional token data in different locations. At this moment, `balances.account` could be a good choice for storing this data.